# How can I import products from external programs CSV every day?

Tags: magento2, import, export

I have external "offline" program that runs database of products. I would like to create a script or something to automaticaly update product inventary.
Another problem is that headers don't mach, so how could i rename headers?

Magento version: 2.3
Server: Ubuntu 18 (LEMP)

I am new to this so any help is apriciated.

Comment: You can do this with our commercial extension https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html - flexible import and export jobs allow you to import and update any kind of data and integrate any system with M2!